# Google Analytics - CORS issue in iOS 10

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We have Google Analytics (UA) deployed through Google Tag Manager. Recently we have been experiencing an issue with some pages not reporting in iOS 10. Looking into it, it seems the request is being rejected due to a CORS issue:

```
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google-analytics.com/collect.
> Cross-origin redirection denied by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing
> policy.
```

The error occurs on some pages but not others:

Example page with the error:

http://www.brownthomas.com

Example page with no error:

http://www.brownthomas.com/brands/jo-malone-london/

Does anyone have a clue as to why this may be happening?